# Find locator with contains text (Robotframework)

Tags: xpath, robotframework

From this code as below:

```html
<a href="javascript:;" id="cTDQo7-a" class="z-menu-cnt z-menu-cnt-img"><span id="cTDQo7-img" class="z-menu-img"></span> payment</a>
<span id="cTDQo7-img" class="z-menu-img"></span>
 "payment"
```

I would like to get locator use keyword contains but the word "payment" is
a lot of the page such as  payment1,payment2,payment3
And id is not unique.

I tried to use the code below but not work for me.

```
//a[contains(.,'payment')]

//span[@class='z-menu-img'] [contains(.,'payment')]

//span[@class='z-menu-img'] and [contains(.,'payment')]

//span[@class='z-menu-img'] contains(.,'payment')
```

Comment: Here is the general notation for xpath `//tagName[@attribute ='attributeValue' and contains(@attribute2, 'attribute2Value')]`. Btw we don't have any span with `payment` text in the above html you provided.

Comment: Have to ask the obvious question: why not use the Id attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 : Use the other attributes in combination with text

```
//a[@class='z-menu-cnt z-menu-cnt-img' and normalize-space(.)='payment']
```

Option 2: Specify the position if you have multiple elements without unique attributes/path

```
(//a[contains(.,'payment')])[1]
```

The second xpath will identify the first occurrence of the link contains text 'payment'. You can change the tagname and index based on your interest.